# Why is my unordered list here appearing outside of the header?

Tags: html, css

[As far as I can tell my CSS is fine, but it just keeps appearing below the header. Any ideas? Sorry for the newb question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mdfl.jpg)

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}


/* Global */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header **/

header {
  background: #35424a;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #e8491d 3px solid;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
  float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight, header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class "container">
    <div id "branding">
      <h1><span>Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

So did I go wrong in the HTML or the CSS, or both? I just can't for the life of me figure out why it's not going in the header, and it's literally driving me crazy.

Comment: Please, [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Instead copy the [relevent code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in the question as text.

Comment: sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Yep, use codepen/jsfiddle and paste only the relevant code there, then please share that with us.

Comment: I just pasted the code in question in my edit, thank you for the help btw. Sorry for my newbness all around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your header h1 element is `display:block` it will take the full width of its parent try adding this to your css code:

```
header h1
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left
}
```